# firebase delete xmlhttp request with equalTo

Tags: json, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, xmlhttprequest, http-delete

```
  DellContact=(emailcontact) => { 
            let {xhttp}=this.DbConn('DELETE','.json?orderBy="email"&equalTo="' + emailcontact + '"');
            xhttp.send();
    }
    
     DbConn (method, addon){
            let xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            let url = "https://phonebook-496ff-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/Contacts" + addon;
            xhttp.open(method,url,true);
            xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            return {xhttp};
        }
```

hello, im trying to delete the specific data from firebase by comparing the JSON value named "email" with the value emailcontact. i get a bad request 400. its something with the request syntax i think, because with GET/POST it works.
firebaseURL/Contact.json?orderBy="email"&equalTo="abc@gmail.com" <-- This is the request that sent
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't support update or delete queries. To delete a node, you need to know its exact path.

So you'll need to:

1. Execute a `GET` for the query to determine the results.
2. Then loop over the results in your application code.
3. Execute a `DELETE` request for each individual result.